# Tychonov's theorem converse

Tags: general-topology

I just want to validate my proof about the converse of Tychonov's theorem that says:

> If the product topology $\prod_{x \in I}X$ is compact, then each $X_i$ is compact

I define the projection function that maps $\prod_{x \in I}X$ to $X_i$ such as:
$P: \prod_{x \in I}X \rightarrow X_i$

We know that $P$ is continuous and since the image of a compact set is compact under continuous function then $X_i$ must be compact

Please let me know if it's a valid argument.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it’s fine.

Comment: At least as long as every factor is nonempty.

Comment: isn't that taken care of by the axiom of choice?

Comment: @user2059456 The axiom of choice tells you that if the spaces are non empty, then the product is non empty. However, the empty space is obviously compact so $\emptyset\times X$ is compact for any $X$. Hence PhoemueX remark that every $X_i$ should be non empty.

Answer (score 3):

The projections are only surjective when all the factors are nonempty. For example $\emptyset \times \mathbb{R} = \emptyset$ is compact, but $\mathbb{R}$ isn't. You have to remember that it's the image of a compact space under a continuous function that is compact, not necessarily the whole codomain.

You're also right to say that you need the axiom of choice when the index set is infinite, but that's in addition to requiring that the factors are nonempty. I'm not sure what happens if you don't assume the axiom of choice (which is equivalent to Tychonoff's theorem anyway...) -- you could potentially get an empty product of an infinite number of noncompact spaces, I imagine.

Otherwise, barring the weird notation (I guess you meant something like $\prod_{x \in I} X_x$ instead of $\prod_{x \in X} X$), your argument is fine.

Comment: Yes you were right about the set of indices it is $I$. And thanks for clarifying why I need to pick non empty factors, it makes sense now.

Comment: Without $\mathsf{AC}$ you can even have a product of countably many $3$-point discrete spaces that is not compact.